# How to modify this custom list environment?

Tags: lists

I am currently trying to fine tune my CV, and I would like to modify a custom list environment I have but I don't know how. I can force the current list environment I have to obtain the desired result, but I am quite sure there is a more LaTeX-y way than manually specifying `\hspace{\fill}\footnotesize{...}` every time in order to achieve what I need.

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\RequirePackage[left=1cm,top=1cm,right=1cm,bottom=1cm,nohead,nofoot]{geometry}

\newdimen\colsep \colsep=1em
\def\topbox#1#2{\vtop{\parindent=0pt \hsize=\dimexpr#1\relax #2}}
\def\entry#1#2#3#4{\par
   \vspace{5pt}\hbox{\topbox{1.75cm}{#1\raggedleft}\kern\colsep
         \topbox{\hsize-2\colsep-1.75cm}{{\bf#2}\hfill {\footnotesize#3}\endgraf#4\strut}}
   \smallskip
} 

\begin{document}

  \entry
    {2022}
    {Conference Title}
    {Something}
    {Paper 1\hspace{\fill}\footnotesize{Place1, year1}\\
    \normalsize{Paper 2}\hspace{\fill}\footnotesize{Place2, year2}}

\end{document}
```

It generates the following output, which I quite like as is:

[image]

I want to obtain the same output but with a code that automatises the spacing and the font sizing in the definition of the list environment rather than manually, such that each entry looks something like this:

```
  \entry
    {2022}
    {Conference Title}
    {Something}
    {{Paper 1}{Place1, year1}}\\
    {{Paper 2}{Place2, year2}}
```

I do not know how to modify my current list environment such that a simpler entry code like the one above generates the desired output. Any help?

Comment: Not a solution to the question, but maybe a tabular would be a better idea than a list?

Comment: I have the entire CV with lists, and since it’s a minor tweak, I’d rather stick to lists. Plus, lists are easier to split across pages…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
  a4paper,
  left=1cm,
  top=1cm,
  right=1cm,
  bottom=1cm,
  nohead,
  nofoot
]{geometry}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\newcommand{\entry}[5]{%
  \par\addvspace{5pt}%
  \begingroup
  \leftskip=1.75cm
  \makebox[0pt][r]{\makebox[\leftskip][l]{#1}}% year
  \textbf{#2}% conference title
  \hfill{\footnotesize #3}% info
  \par\nopagebreak
  #4\par\pagebreak[0]\addvspace{5pt}
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand{\paper}[2]{#1\hfill{\footnotesize#2}\par\nopagebreak}

\begin{document}

\entry{2022}
  {Conference Title}
  {Something}
  {
   \paper{Paper 1}{Place1, year1}
   \paper{Paper 2}{Place2, year2}
  }

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, @egreg. I had to modify your answer a bit in order to get the desired result, but it does what the question asks for and it was enough for me to get where I wanted to. Hence, I have accepted it. Thank you again!